# How can I animate colors spreading over an object?

Tags: animation, texturing, color, panoramic

I created a map that shows segments of it turning into a single bright color you can see here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIlvZ55-NW8&feature=youtu.be

I created this by separating each color section into it's own object and then animating a color on top of the map texture.  Is there a way to do this where I can animate the colors spreading across the surface and blend with each other instead of simply raising the opacity?  Or a way where I can just keep the one object?

BTW this is a 360 video for a VR project I'm working on, hence the equirectangular perspective.

Here's an example of what I am looking for.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvFl6UBZLv4

I was hoping to use the Texture Paint brush but I can't seem to animate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Those are tough to achieve. Have you looked into shapekeys for more organic deformations? Those could be rendered separately then composited over, to avoid rendering lots of animation frames

Comment: Create an animation of black to white then use this animation as the Factor in a Mix Node to mix the destination colour and a transparent node. As for creating the animation you could use a Gradient animation (will only produce a rough shape) or investigate Dynamic Paint and "draw" the animation with another object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a quick test and the way I would do it is to use the Build modifier.

Create a 3D mesh of the area to be coloured, remove any vertices to make it 2D. If you do not do it like that I have found the Remesh modifier either does not work or produces strange results.

Apply a Remesh modifier set to create blocks. This creates a "pixelated" mesh but you can tweak the Octree depth to de-pixelate it. Apply this modifier, as we need direct access to the new geometry.

Tab into Edit mode and select all ('a') then position the cursor at the location you want the colour to spread from. From the Mesh menu select "Sort Elements" and select "Cursor Distance".

Tab out of Edit mode and add a Build modifier, set the duration and hit play.

The mesh will build itself one face at a time spreading from your sorted start location.

If that solution does not produce a neat enough solution then I would suggest a black & white animation as a factor mask in Nodes. Or you could use Dynamic paint and "paint" the colour with another object.